# How to open Pull request in Repository A to Repository B with github actions

Tags: github-actions

Having 2 Repository A and B. I'd like to open pull request in Repo B when something is updated in Repo A by using github workflow actions.
I want to build this process without any plugins and only want to build in Repo A. How can I do this?

Here is my workflow:

```yaml
name: Create Pull Request to B

on:
  push:
    branches: [test]

jobs:
  create-pull-request:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Create Branch
        run: |
          git checkout -b branchB
          git push origin branchB

      - name: Create Pull Request
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          curl -X POST \
            -H “Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json” \
            -H “Authorization: Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN” \
            https://api.github.com/repos/givvemee/bot-test2/pulls \
            -d ‘{“title”:“Update from A”, “body”: “This pull request is automatically created from repository A”, “head”: “branchB”, “base”: “main”}’
```

This returns:

```
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.
```

and nothing is working. How can i resolve this?

I'd like to open pull request in Repo B when something is updated in Repo A by using GitHub actions workflow.

I want to build this process without any plugins and only want to build in Repo A. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the `curl` call a copy/paste? Seems like those quotes are different.

Comment: You can check the `curl` command with https://www.shellcheck.net/.